Cannot login to Azure API Management Developer Portal with AAD
I have a Basic tier APIM instance.  Yes, the Docs clearly say Entra is not supported for Basic, however it isn't clear if you can set it up manually and get it to work anyway.  I did just that, following these MS docs How to add AAD.  I was able to complete the steps, and added an AD Group.  I launch the portal, click the AAD button and the authorization works fine, but after entering MFA I get "Server Error" on the UI. Browser F12 reveals 401 and 400 errors, similar to this post. I expect to see the "Complete Sign Up" page but it doesn't get there.
I decode the jwt in the Request auth header and I can see the claims, etc.  I don't particularly want to upgrade to Standard, price is x5.  I cannot try Basic V2, it's not avail in our region.
Any thoughts?  Did it allow me to get through all that config successfully with only Basic, allow me to authorize fine, only to slam the gates down when trying to get to the Complete Sign In page?  Thanks in advance!
I simply followed MS Docs, and it worked 95% to the end. I expect to see the "Complete Sign In" page after AAD authorization but it gives 401. I've also republished the Portal a few times.

I also have followed Manually enable Microsoft Entra application and identity provider documentation in Basic tier and added Azure AD in identities.


Then I published the site and opened the developer portal in incognito mode, choose Azure Active Directory Option which then lead to Complete Sign up page. I have added user details to complete the signup process and user got added successfully.


I can now login as a newly added user too.


Thanks for the confirmation and screenshots. Doesn't look like I missed anything, but it's just not working.  I manually constructed the signup URL from your browser screenshot:
https://xxxxxx/signup-oauth#provider=Aad&token=yyyyy
This successfully rendered the "complete sign up page", but filling it in still gives "400 Bad Request".

While adding the Identity which client library you choose like MSAL or ADAL? I have chosen ADAL, check my screenshot and also have you added the Redirect URL correctly in Azure AD?

Again appreciate your comments.  I was indeed using MSAL, I switched to ADAL (changing Registration SPA to Web) but behaviour stays the same:  auth works but then fails to show Complete Sign Up page with 401 and 400 errors.

Have you added the redirect url?

Please try in incognito mode. I was using ***/signin page in incognito mode

OK I finally figured it out.  Turns out that it is because my account/email was the Administrator.  According to this doc Access and customize the developer portal, admins should be able to browse the portal normally via an Incognito/Private window, but that is not the case at least for me.
I switched admin with another colleague, and now he cannot browse and sees the "Server Error", and it works normally for me. When I go to signin to the Developer Portal by clicking the AAD button, there's a 5 second delay and it provisioned my account for me without showing the "complete sign-in page".
