Server error occured while using B2C on Azure API Management Develop portal
I want to add the ability to sign in or up for my APIM developer portal via any Microsoft account type (personal or corporate, work ...).
I have uploaded SocialAndLocalAccounts custom policy from the starter pack (removed the Facebook provider and added AADCommon-OpenIdConnect) - I have attached these files below.
I have errors while I'm trying to sign up via a local or Microsoft account.
Let's try to look Microsoft account (multitenant)

Click "Multi-Tenant ADD" button


When you filled the email and password, you will be redirected to  webPortal.com/signup-oauth#provider=AadB2C&token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZ...


Looks like, all is good except that we have lost the session, and   when we press "sign up" button, we get an exception:


the JWT token



Similar behavior I have when I try to sign up via a local account, but on the first step - record with user created in b2c tenant and then we can sign in by login and password:

When I filled email and password and confirmed email address,  this one error, and 401 error code for "/identity", and 403 for "/users" endpoints .

The requests to Users and Identity have a header:  Authorization: AadB2C
id_token="eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZC....."



When I try to click "Microsoft Account" again - server redirects me to this one page:


The jwt from the local account is this one:



So, Azure Active Directory B2C tenant has:

App registrations  - apimb2cdemo with secret code, that I have set to
APIM Identity (Accounts in any identity provider or organizational
directory (for authenticating users with user flows))
SocialAndLocalAccounts custom policy from the starter pack (Attached)
app registrations - ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework - app (Accounts
in this organizational directory only (Tenant only - Single tenant))
app registrations - IdentityExperienceFramework - app (Accounts in
this organizational directory only (Tenant only - Single tenant))
app registrations - webapp1 - app (just for testing - jwt.ms)
(Accounts in any identity provider or organizational directory (for authenticating users with user flows))

APIM Developer portal tenant has:

app registrations - Azure AD B2C App  with secret code, that I have
set to my ClaimsProvider in TrustFrameworkExtensions


Redirect URL:
https://your-b2c-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/your-B2C-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp

(Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID
tenant - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype,
Xbox))  - Here, I chose a different option compared to the article



new one Identity provider in APIM Developer portal Menu

Azure Active Directory B2C - has reference to apimb2cdemo app with id
and secret key and custom policy name and Client library - MSAL.


For this task, I am using these tutorials:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy (from 1 to 3 tutorials)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-aad-b2c
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy
Here I have left custom policies that I'm using -
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1F1uBgF1R96dTUVziNOrw2WTH6dd_xCUH?usp=sharing
I have no idea what happened and why I have faced these issues, could you please assist me with this issue?
I'm looking forward to any ideas and solutions.
Thank you in advance!

First thing with custom policies - look at the logs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Can you share the exception message you are getting in complete sign up page

@IkhtesamAfrin If you are asking about the request to "identity" endpoint in multiple tenant cases - I am getting 401 Unauthorized status code, without any response data...
Before sending a request to identity, I have a request to Token, and this request returns OK.  Looks like, my APIM dev portal can't manage
AadB2C id_token="eyJh" in header
Do I need to configure AOuth 2.0 or Open connect ID in  Azure APIM Develop Portal?

Have you tried to open the developer portal in private mode or in incognito mode? As if you will open in normal browser then it will take your login credential

@IkhtesamAfrin Yeah, I have always used it on incognito mode in Chrome, because, I'm trying to use a different profile.

Refer to this SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78675204/cannot-login-to-azure-api-management-developer-portal-with-aad/78676637#78676637

@IkhtesamAfrin I have changed to ADAL, in incognito browser when I try to click "Microsoft account" button -  I have this exception: AADB2C90057: The provided application is not configured to allow the 'OAuth' Implicit flow. Correlation ID: f03bf928-63cd-4aed-9c93-bc24b6c2c475 Timestamp: 2024-07-04 10:47:21Z
All applications has Access tokens (used for implicit flows) = true, and ID tokens (used for implicit and hybrid flows) = true

Have you ticked Access token and ID tokens check box? Also have you added the redirect URL?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@IkhtesamAfrin, thanks for help. I have fixed this issue.

I'm glad to inform you that I have fixed this issue.
In my case:
I have changed to ADAL library and missed a claim (oid).
User’s ObjectID(oid) and Subject(sub) claims in AADB2C token are necessary for APIM to identify the caller of APIM user creation call from developer portal. Lacking either of these two claims will cause AccessDenied issue.
